# Lua: strange behavior with loadstring?

Tags: lua, self

I am using `loadstring` with Lua 5.1:

**Main**

```
function Object:load_string(str)
    loadstring(str)() -- self in this is 'nil'
    print(self) -- self here is a 'table'
end
obj:load_string('print(self)')
```

**Output**

```
> nil
> table: 1557C890
```

Why is it that the `self` used in `loadstring` resolves to a `nil` value when the `self` variable is accessible in the function and can be printed directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code contained in string (or file) is not related to current scope in any way. `loadstring()` creates new anonymous vararg function. You must pass `self` explicitly.

```
function Object:load_string(str)
    loadstring(str)(self) -- pass self explicitly
    print(self) -- self here is a 'table'
end

obj:load_string('local self = ...; print(self)')
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, the code in `str` contains a reference to `self` *as a global variable*. The `self` in `load_string` is a *local* variable, not accessible to the code in `str`.